# Image animation on resize window

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, onresize

I was wondering if it is possible to animate a logo between different sizes like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c1/41/9f/c1419f1eee2c8a4df986b97fea5b131e.jpg) on window resize

so when the window is resized to a smaller window, the logo animates to a smaller variant and vice versa.

i am not really interested in the animation, but more on how to combine the window resize with the animation.

I know that there is a javascript onresize Event and that its possible to animate a logo using javascript.

I dont know wether its best to animate in JS or CSS.

i'm trying to do it with just html, css and javascript.

Comment: So your less concerned on how to handle the animation but more curious about the stages in code that would undertake?

Comment: You can use different logos and change it with js or with css media queries according to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is a little unclear in your post.
To identify the varying window resizes you can choose the following css code based of the resolution of varying devices.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

According to your post, you wanted to animate a logo. To this accordingly, put the animation of the logo inside one of the css resolution restrictions.

The following code was taken from:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

If you want more information on window resizing click on the link above.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

> I was wondering if it is possible to animate a logo between different sizes like this on window resize

Yes, you can do that, and there are a couple of options.

> I don't know wether its best to animate in JS or CSS

I would say that it depends on your animation. CSS [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) is usually "lighter" than Javascript, but may not work for complex animations. In the other hand, you have Javascript options like [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/), [Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/) (and others) that will allow you to have more complex animations and are usually more compatible across browser and devices. They will require extra libraries in your code though.

> how to combine the window resize with the animation

You can either use CSS with **media queries** (as explained in Shean's answer), or Javascript **resize events** (as you said). I would recommend using CSS media queries if your animation is in CSS, and Javascript resize events if your animation is in Javascript. You could mix those, but I don't think it is a good idea.

Here are 2 basic examples (one for a CSS animation and another one for a JS animation):

## CSS animation

You could have this HTML structure:

```
<body>
  <div class="my-logo">
    My logo here
  </div>
</body>
```

And this CSS code:

```
/* This will show in small screens */
.my-logo {
  // Your CSS animation code here
}

/* This will show in bigger screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .my-logo {
      // Your CSS animation code here
    }
}
```

## Javascript animation

You could have this HTML structure:

```
<body>
  <div id="smallLogo">
    My small logo animation here
  </div>
  <div id="bigLogo">
    My big logo animation here
  </div>
</body>
```

And this Javascript:

```
function handleLogoDisplay() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    document.getElementById("smallLogo").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("bigLogo").style.display = "none"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("smallLogo").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("bigLogo").style.display = "block"
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', handleLogoDisplay);
```